# Does the series $\sum \frac{\sin p}{p}$, where $p$ prime, converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

**Question.** *Assume that $\{p_n\}$ is the sequence of prime numbers, in increasing order. Does the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin p_n}{p_n}
$$
converge?*

The only criterion to establish convergence that I can think of, which might be of any use, is the [Abel's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test), which requires that the partial sums of the sequence $b_n=\sin p_n$ are bounded, i.e., that there exists an $M>0$, such that
$$
|\sin p_1+\cdots+\sin p_n|\le M, \quad\text{for all $n\in\mathbb N$}.
$$

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you could use Dirichlet's test here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272248/regarding-the-sum-sum-p-textprime-sin-p?rq=1