# Is $\ \{ \sin(p):\ p\ $ is prime $ \}\ $ a dense subset of $\ [-1,1]\ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

> Is the set $A:= \{ \sin(p): \text{$p$ is prime} \}$ a dense subset of
> $[-1,1]$? Is it known whether or not $-1$, $0$ or $1$ are
> limit points of $A$?

I would imagine so, otherwise this means the primes are related to $\pi$ in some special way, which I have not heard of. I'm not sure how to prove the affirmative though: I think the unpredictable nature of the primes makes this a challenge. All I know is that $\{ \sin(n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a dense subset of $[-1,1]$. For example, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1). There are many known inequalities and bounds for the prime counting function, for example, see [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) However, I'm not sure these are useful for answering the above question.

Comment: There's probably some result about the uniform distribution of the fractional part of $p\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a fixed irrational and $p$ runs through the primes, probably somewhere in the Kuipers and Niederreiter book. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272248/regarding-the-sum-sum-p-textprime-sin-p also looks relevant.

Comment: Found it. Page 22 of K & N, Uniform Distribution of Sequences, it says, "... it is known that $(p_n\theta)$, $n=1,2,\dots$, is u.d. mod $1$, where $p_1=2$, $p_2=3,\dots,p_n,\dots$ is the sequence of primes arranged in ascending order." Here $\theta$ is an arbitrary (real) irrational, and $(x)$ is the fractional part of $x$. References are given to work by Vinogradov and by Hua, e.g., Chapter 11 of Vinogradov's book, The Method of Trigonometric Sums in the Theory of Numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently I. M. Vinogradov proved it's dense in $1935.$  Though not equally distributed.

This is a theorem in Algebraic number theory.

That $\{-1,0,1\}$ are limit points is a trivial consequence.

Comment: To be clear: Vinogradov proved only that the set is dense, not that it is uniformly distributed.  Nevertheless it almost certainly *is* uniformly distributed as well.  Correct?

Comment: My guess is that he proved that it is not uniformly distributed.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Intuitively, rather than a uniform distribution, it's more likely we would have density near $x$ proportional to $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$, since that's what we would get if $p$ were uniformly distributed in $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Yes, good point.  So it’s most likely that the distribution is the same as if $p$ were uniformly random.